# make usertype see different content in header

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to make a website with asp.net.

I've got users table with different users, they all have their own usertype, by defauly it's "U" as in User. For admins it's "A" as in administrator.

My website also has a header section. I want my code to read which usertype currently has the session active and assign the header menu with either UserHome if it's "U" usertype, or Adminpanel if it's "A" usertype.

How do i do that? I tried this way, but it didn't work.

```
{

    String CS = 

ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BoothsConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))

    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Users", con);

        con.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        string Utype;
        Utype = dt.Rows[0][5].ToString().Trim();
        if (Utype == "U")
        {

            userhome.Visible = true;
            adminpanel.Visible = false;
        }
        if (Utype == "A")
        {
            adminpanel.Visible = true;
            userhome.Visible = false;
        }
   }
}
```

html part:

```
<li><a href="adminhome.aspx" runat="server" id="admin">admin</a></li>
<li><a href="userhome.aspx" runat="server" id="user">user</a></li>
```

---

newest edit:

```
 private void CheckUserType()
    {
            String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BoothsConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Usertype from Users where usertype = @usertype", con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@usertype", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = Session["usertype"].ToString();
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);

                string Utype;
                Utype = dt.Rows[0][5].ToString().Trim();
                if (Utype == "U")
                {
                    user.Visible = true;
                    admin.Visible = false;
                }
                else if (Utype == "A")
                {
                    admin.Visible = true;
                    user.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is not working?  Is nothing displaying?  Are both displaying?  Can you post your HTML as well?  When you debug is your value for Utype being set correctly?  The panels are not working?  Or is your Utype value not being set correctly?  That will help narrow down where issue is.

Comment: If you want to get info about the current user, then why are you selecting all users from the database and not just the current user?

Comment: Hello, Brad! Right now it displays only adminpanel, the userpanel doesn't show even if usertype == u in database.

Comment: @janekjan that's not quite all the details you were asked for by Brad...

Comment: ADyson so this value must read from the current session?

Comment: If that's where you're storing the current user identity then yes you should use that value to restrict your query. P.S. I am still on the page, but if I leave it, and you want my attention, you have to tag me in the comment with @ before my username, or else I will not see any notification about it :-)

Comment: As the couple people above say:  You are selecting all users is your first problem.  Second you did mention you want to get from session, so you depending on how you are setting session that UType should be int the session (session variable or session table) and pull it from there

Comment: An additional note, it is never good idea to select * from a table, especially if you only need 1 value from the table, just select that field.

Comment: i guess reading it from the session would be my way, are there any solutions?

Comment: to read something from the session? Yes, assuming you actually have something in the session you can read. You haven't shown us how you hold the details of the currently logged in user, so we can't help you very easily. Anyway you can easily google how to read variables from the session. What specifically is the issue?

Comment: @ADyson please, check my newest edit, this code doesn't work but maybe it's not too far off. System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState.this[string].get returned null.

Comment: Did you define `Session["usertype"]` somewhere else in your code at a time before this piece of code got executed? e.g. by writing `Session["usertype"] = "U"` or whatever

Comment: No, i didn't. wouldn't that overwrite that usertype to always assign it to "U"?

Comment: well yes that was just a simple example. But presumably you defined it somehow, based on the user detail, after they logged in? If you want to read that value you have to write it first...

Comment: Hang on though...your query still makes no sense...it will fetch all users whose usertype matches a certain value. If you want to display the correct heading for the _current user_, then you have to request _only_ the _current user_ from the database, and get their usertype. Right now your query is circular - if you already know the user type from the session, then you don't need to write a query to get the usertype!! Stand back and think about your logic for a moment. I guess you actually want to query based on the user's Username or ID. Then you can get just one result.